# JSX using Typescript generics to render components instead of using a switch

Tags: typescript, jsx

Currently I have this to render some JSX depending on an enum type:

```
enum NavigationScreenType {
    SplashScreen,
    LoginSelectionScreen,
    LoginScreen,
}

    private getJSXFromScreenType(type: NavigationScreenType, props?: object): JSX.Element {
        switch (type) {
            case NavigationScreenType.LoginSelectionScreen:
                return (<LoginSelectionScreen {...props} />);
            case NavigationScreenType.LoginScreen:
                return (<LoginScreen {...props} />);
            default:
                return (<SplashScreen {...props}/>);
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to achieve this using generics instead? I intend to modify the function to accept a type and return in a single line something along the lines of:

```
    private getJSXFromScreenType<T extends BaseNavigationScreen>(type: T, props?: object): JSX.Element {
        return (<type {...props}/>);
    }
```

Comment: The question is not very clear. What do you mean when you say "using generics"? What would your solution ideally look like? However it may be, the answer to your question will probably be something along the lines of "generics are a compile-time construct, and type information is not available at runtime".

Comment: I've updated the question to be a bit more clear but I intend to use the signature: `private getJSXFromScreenTypeZ<T>(type: T, props?: object): JSX.Element {`